# Windows.h Included, but LARGE_INTEGER, etc. are Undefined

Tags: c++, windows

I'm working on a C++ project, and wrote this simple timer class in "timer.h":

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>

namespace mobius {

    class Timer
    {
    private:
        LARGE_INTEGER m_Start;
        double m_Frequency;
    public:
        Timer()
        {
            LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
            QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
            m_Frequency = 1.0 / frequency.QuadPart;
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_Start);
        }

        void reset()
        {
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_Start);
        }

        float elapsed()
        {
            LARGE_INTEGER current;
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&current);
            unsigned __int64 cycles = current.QuadPart - m_Start.QuadPart;
            m_Start = current;
            return (float)(cycles * m_Frequency);
        }
    };

}
```

The code has been working fine for the last two weeks, but it just suddenly broke. When I try to compile my project, I get the following errors:

```
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(10,24): error C3646: 'm_Start': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(10,24): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(15,4): error C2065: 'LARGE_INTEGER': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(15,18): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'frequency'
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(15,18): error C2065: 'frequency': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(16,31): error C2065: 'frequency': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(16,4): error C3861: 'QueryPerformanceFrequency': identifier not found
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(17,24): error C2065: 'frequency': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(18,29): error C2065: 'm_Start': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(18,4): error C3861: 'QueryPerformanceCounter': identifier not found
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(23,29): error C2065: 'm_Start': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(23,4): error C3861: 'QueryPerformanceCounter': identifier not found
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(28,4): error C2065: 'LARGE_INTEGER': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(28,18): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'current'
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(28,18): error C2065: 'current': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(29,29): error C2065: 'current': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(29,4): error C3861: 'QueryPerformanceCounter': identifier not found
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(30,30): error C2065: 'current': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(30,49): error C2065: 'm_Start': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(31,4): error C2065: 'm_Start': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\seele\Documents\C\GameFramework\Game\Game\src\utils\timer.h(31,14): error C2065: 'current': undeclared identifier
```

It seems as if Windows.h isn't actually being properly included. The Windows.h file has a preprocessor block that is disabled if _WINDOWS_ is defined. Perhaps when I include Window.h in timer.h, _WINDOWS_ is somehow already defined, which would mean that Windows.h isn't actually defining anything. However, this is just speculation.

Has anybody experienced this before? If so, how do I fix it?

EDIT: The code is still not working but I decided to rewrite the class to use std::chrono::steady clock. It's working fine now, but I think I might want to improve the code a little bit at a later date:

```
#pragma once

#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

namespace mobius {

    class Timer
    {
    private:
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point m_Start;
    public:
        Timer()
        {
            reset();
        }

        void reset()
        {
            m_Start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        }

        float elapsed()
        {
            std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point current = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            std::chrono::duration<double> time_span = current - m_Start;
            return (float)(time_span.count());
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: If you make a minimal project with just that code in it does it work? It does for me. If it does for you then you need to systematically remove chunks of your non working project until the error goes away, then slowly add things back until you find what is causing the problem. Source control helps greatly with this since you can easily go back in time and see what's changed from when it was working.

Comment: Well, I haven't tested that, but when I remake the file the red squiggles go away. The program still doesn't compile though

Comment: Note: [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps) may not return the result you expect. If you need a monotonic clock there are better ways.

Comment: I really haven't changed anything, so I assume it's some kind of glitch.

Comment: It's just supposed to be a simple timer to test performance.

Comment: @TheDigitalOdyssey it returns 10MHz if you're in a VM regardless of actual reality. If you need wall time there are better choices.

Comment: Some other troubleshotting steps. Batch build -> select all -> clean, then rebuild. If you're using precompiled headers try turning them off.

Comment: Oh, that's weird. Do you have a recommendation for what I should be using instead?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ok, trying that now

Comment: @RetiredNinja Precompiled headers are already off. Tried cleaning and rebuilding and I still have the same problem. I also tried restarting my computer

Comment: Due diligence comment: Have you checked that [std::chrono::steady_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) doesn't give you the precision you require for a lot less work?

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks, I'll look into that

Comment: Include details of which compiler version and build you are using, and the build command

Comment: Your use of `duration_cast` is superfluous (only harms readability).  It can be simplified to: `std::chrono::duration<double> time_span = current - m_Start;`